# Topology. we have to prove $\mathbb{X}$ is hausdorff space on real valued continuous function.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

If, for any two distinct points $x$ and $y$ in a topological space $\mathbb{X}$, there is always a real-valued continuous function such that $f(x) ≠ f(y)$, prove that $\mathbb{X}$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: And please use mathjax for mathematical symbols and formulae. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Concerning the actual question: You want to use that the real numbers is a Hausdorff space, and the definition of a continuous function. From there it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?. Where are you stuck?.

Comment: x,y belong to X. x is not equal to y. A continuous f , f belongs to T. And f(x) is not equal to f(y) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(x)\neq f(y)$, you can create two open sets $U,V\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\in U$, $f(y)\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

For example, $U=\{r\in\mathbb{R}:|r-f(x)|<\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{2}\}$ and $V=\{r\in\mathbb{R}:|r-f(y)|<\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{2}\}$. These are two open intervals that don't intersect.

Now, $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ don't intersect either. (For example, every $z\in f^{-1}(U)$ has the property that $f(z)\in U$. But if $f(z)\in U$, then $f(z)\notin V$. Remember, $U$ and $V$ don't intersect.)

But $f^{-1}(U)$ and $f^{-1}(V)$ are also open sets.

This proves the Hausdorff property.

Comment: simpler: find $z$ strictly inbetween $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ and use $U=(-\infty,z)$ and $V=(z,\infty)$ (order topology open).